# Using array_count_values result in a foreach loop

Tags: php

I have an `array` of IDs, lots of the IDs occur multiple times and I'm using `array_count_values()` to count how many times each ones occurs.

I want to do something if a specific ID occurs more than 3 times, I just can't figure out how to get the `array_count_values()` result into a foreach loop so I can use it.

Any help appreciated!

```
$array = array("297","297","297","297","188","188"); 

print_r( array_count_values($array) );

// loop room booking data
foreach($array as $key => $val) {

    // if the ID occurs more than 3 times
    if ( $val > '3' ) {
        // do something
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the `array_count_value` result to a variable and pass this value to foreach loop like below

```
    <?php 
    $array = array("297","297","297","297","188","188"); 

    $array1 = array_count_values($array); // assign result to array1 variable

    // loop room booking data
    foreach($array1 as $key => $val) {

        // if the ID occurs more than 10 times
        if ( $val > '3' ) {
            // do something
            echo $key; // return value e.g 297
            echo $value; // return no. of times ID occure e.g. 4

        }

    }
    ?>
```

[running Code](https://eval.in/831889)

Comment: Thanks that works, but how do I echo the ID which occurs more than 3 times in the //do something section? I can only seem to get the value of how many times the ID has occured, but not the actual ID

Comment: @TheBobster check my code I have `echo $key` it will gives you ID

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that!

Comment: @TheBobster if its working for you please accept this as answer

Answer (score 3):

Assign the result of the function to a variable, then loop over that variable.

```
$frequencies = array_count_values($array);
foreach ($frequencies as $id => $count) {
    if ($count > 3) {
        echo "$id occurs $count times<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works, but how do I echo the ID which occurs more than 3 times in the //do something section? I can only seem to get the value of how many times the ID has occured, but not the actual ID

Comment: `$key` contains the ID.